# How implement the following chart in google chart api?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I want to implement the following chart in google chart api. how can i get it. I want to separate 4 quarters between two data points and indicators for each quarters need to display. And vertical line with number is that point has annotations. how can i get this in google chart api.

[image]

Comment: Check `annotations` option for line chart.

Comment: I think the only one way is to add code that changes SVG markup after the chart is drawn. Or use some other chart framework, but it will still require writing custom code.

Comment: Did you find a good way to do this with any js library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an "annotation" role column to create the lines you want.  Here's an example:

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('number', 'Year');
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    data.addRows([
        [2009, null, 5],
        [2010, '1', 4],
        [2011, null, 7],
        [2011.25, '2', null],
        [2011.5, '3', null],
        [2012, null, 7]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        interpolateNulls: true,
        annotation: {
            1: {
                style: 'line'
            }
        },
        hAxis: {
            format: '#',
            minorGridlines: {
                count: 3
            },
            ticks: [2009, 2010, 2011, 2012]
        },
        vAxis: {
            textPosition: 'none',
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 10
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        }
    });
};
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/H5K29/

Comment: is any way to get the annotation to the top of the chart as like the expected chart shown above?

Comment: No, you cannot control the positioning of the text.